# How to hide mouse pointer/cursor when over Android View?

Tags: android, mouse, mouse-cursor

When you connect mouse to Android device and see cursor on the screen, I want it to disappear when it’s over my view. I want to to provide custom user experience for this view that is different from default system cursor.

Comment: I'd severely recommend against this.  People using a mouse are doing so for a reason.  They want to use a mouse.  It may even be an accessibility concern for them-  people with some nerve conditions can use mice more accurately that their fingers.  If they want to use a mouse, let them.  Doing otherwise won't make them amazed at how great your app is, it will lead them to using an alternative because you think you know better.

Comment: I appreciate your comment Gabe and for the most part I agree with it - especially accessibility is important thing to highlight. Still I think there are cases where it might be a viable option (e.g. cursor stickiness, custom cursor behaviour) but they should be exception to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve that:

The simplest way is to use [View.setPointerIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setPointerIcon(android.view.PointerIcon)) which allows to set custom pointer icon. Android API has useful helper method for not showing cursor at all: `PointerIcon.getNullIcon()`. So combining it all in Kotlin it’ll be:

```
myView.pointerIcon = PointerIcon.getNullIcon()
```

For more advanced use cases you can request pointer capture ([official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures/movement#pointer-capture)).
in short:

1. when view is focused (e.g. clicked) you can request pointer capture with [View.requestPointerCapture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestPointerCapture())
2. Then either override [onCapturedPointerEvent(MotionEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onCapturedPointerEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)%5D) or register [OnCapturedPointerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnCapturedPointerListener)
3. Remember to release capture when no longer needed with [View.releasePointerCapture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#releasePointerCapture())

Remember that to request pointer capture **the view hierarchy that contains the view must have focus**.